# Lumen 5.1 Auth::attempt Not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I am using `lumen 5.1.*`  but whenever i use Auth it will throw an error

> ErrorException in AuthManager.php line 16: Missing argument 1 for
>   Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::createDriver(), called in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\illuminate\support\Manager.php on line
>   87 and defined

Can any one help me how to fix this issue .I need to use `Auth::user()` in lumen

```
public function postLogin(Request $request){


       if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            echo "success";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r(Auth::user()->toArray());
        } else {
            echo "sorry erorr occured";
        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your `Auth::attempet();` ?  can i see?

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade.I updated question

Comment: `if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'activated' => 1])); `   did you check this?

Comment: @ya not working even auth::user() also not working

Comment: `auth()->user();`  helper function works in lumen

Comment: what happens if add 'driver' => 'eloquent' into your created auth.php file.

Comment: @Leo instanceof Kelmendi.I have already

Answer (score 0):

settings your `.env` file then check

[lumen-api-oauth/.env.example](https://github.com/esbenp/lumen-api-oauth/blob/master/.env.example)

Comment: `AUTH_MODEL=App\Auth\User`

Comment: @vision I updated my answer please follow the link https://github.com/esbenp/lumen-api-oauth/blob/master/.env.example